# Can the convergence of inner products be 'closed'?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

For $(H, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ a separable real Hilbert space and $K\subset H$ compact, let $(u_k)$ be a sequence in $H$ such that $(\langle u_k, v\rangle)$ converges for each $v\in K$.

Are there [non-trivialising] conditions on $(u_k)$ and $K$ which imply that

$$\tag{1}
\exists \ u\in H \quad \text{with} \quad \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\langle u_k, \cdot\rangle = \langle u, \cdot\rangle \ \text{ pointwise on } K \ ? 
$$

Comment: Having $(u_k)$ bounded in norm should suffice - use Alaoglu to pick a weak limit point $u$, which will satisfy (1).  But maybe that is not what you are looking for?

Comment: ...and boundedness in norm is equivalent to the boundedness of the sequences $\langle u_k,v\rangle$ for all $v\in H$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for your comment. Boundedness of $(u_k)$ is indeed not quite what I am looking for, because this is an $H$-global condition on the $(u_k)$, as Jochen said,  while I can really only evaluate the properties of $\langle u_k, \cdot \rangle$ as functions on $K$.

Comment: Could it be of any help if the $(\langle u_k, \cdot\rangle)$ converged uniformly on $K$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What follows is an example that the uniform convergence on $K$ does not suffice. Let $\{e_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ be an orthonormal basis. Consider
$$v_n=\sum_{j=1}^n 2^{-j}e_j,\quad v=\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j}e_j$$ and $K= \{v_n\,:\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup \{v\} .$ Then $K$ is compact. For $u_k=\sum_{j=1}^ke_j$ we have
$$\lim_k\langle u_k,v_n\rangle =\sum_{j=1}^n2^{-j},\quad \lim_k\langle u_k,v\rangle =1\quad (*)$$
However there is no element $u$ such that
$$\langle u,v_n\rangle =\sum_{j=1}^n2^{-j},\quad n\in \mathbb{N}\quad (**)$$ Indeed if $u=\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_je_j,$ then $(**)$ implies $a_j=1$ for all $j.$
Moreover the convergence in $(*)$ is uniform as
$$0\le \sum_{j=1}^n2^{-j}-\langle u_k,v_n\rangle =\begin{cases} \sum_{j=k+1}^n2^{-j} & k<n\\
0 & k\ge n
\end{cases} \\
\le \sum_{j=k+1}^\infty 2^{-j}=2^{-k}$$

The same holds for the larger compact set $$K=\{v\,:\,|\langle v,e_j\rangle |\le \alpha_j\}$$ for a fixed square summable nonnegative sequence $\alpha_j$ and the same choice of $u_k.$